# Generate missing nested objects while using Vue.$set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

How to generate missing nested objects (like `bar`, `a`, `b` and `c`) when using `Vue.$set` the way below ?

```
export const mutations = {
  UPDATE(state, payload) {
    this._vm.$set(state.foo.bar.a.b.c, payload.key, payload.value)
  }
}
```

Instead of `state.foo.bar.a.b.c`, I'm actually using `_.get(state, payload.path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have included should work. Are you getting an error?

**EDIT:**

Okay, I think I understand now - so based on your example, e.g. `b` might not exist yet and should be created if so.

I don't think `Vue.$set` will do this automatically but you could use a custom solution like this, which should create any objects that are missing along the chain of `payload.path`:

```
      let objectLevels = payload.path.split('.');
      const propToChange = objectLevels.reduce((res, level) => {
        if (!res[level]) this.$set(res, level, {});
        return res[level];
      }, state);
      this.$set(propToChange, payload.key, payload.value);
```

Comment: I'm getting this warning: `[Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: undefined`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a suggested solution.